# Money is not increased after payment Coinbase

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem
with Coinbase
When recharging the account with $5, for example, the payment process is completed, but the account remains $0

PayPal works without problems. Can you solve this code for me?

```
       
    elseif($method_id == 24):
        

           $amount = (double)$amount;

    $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO payments SET client_id=:c_id, payment_amount=:amount, payment_privatecode=:code, payment_method=:method, payment_mode=:mode, payment_create_date=:date, payment_ip=:ip, payment_extra=:extra");
          $insert->execute(array("c_id" => $user['client_id'], "amount" => $amount, "code" => $paymentCode, "method" => $method_id, "mode" => "", "date" => date("Y.m.d H:i:s"), "ip" => GetIP(), "extra" => $paymentCode));
          $success = 1;
          $successText = "Your payment was initiated successfully, you are being redirected..";
          
   
    
        $data = [
             "redirect_url"=> "https://webhook.site/8c16529b-dab9-4a62-af0e-ea759d1f7abf",
            "business_name" => "Wixout", 
            "customer_email" => $user['email'], 
            "customer_name" => $user['client_id'].','.$paymentCode.','.$method_id.','.$paymentCode, 
            "local_price" => [
                  "amount" => $amount, 
                  "currency" => "USD" 
               ], 
            "memo" => "Balance recharge - ".  $user['email'] 
         ];  
         $fields_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/invoices');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Api-Key: '.$extra['api_key'];
$headers[] = 'X-Cc-Version: 2018-03-22';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

//echo $result;
   
$result=json_decode($result);
header('location:'.$result->data->hosted_url);
exit;
       


elseif ($method_id == 26):
```

Thank you all

I tried all the solutions because in my experience I didn't find a solution

Comment: Hi, have you considered [using a webhook](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/commerce/docs/webhooks) instead? This would probably work better for your use case.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Is there a way to replace this code and put webhooks instead?

Comment: Yes, you'd refactor by moving purchase validation and database updates to the webhook.  I've linked their documentation in the comment above, which itself links some information on what events they send and best practice for securing them. You'd ideally want to make sure the customer know the payment is processing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not understand anything. I tried and tried, but it did not work for me